# Algorithm for matching words in two lists while minimizing the total sum of (squared) distances

Tags: algorithm, sum, distance

I have two lists of words, say `list1` and `list2`, where one of them is shorter than the other, and the shorter list is supposed to have the same words as the larger one. The words in each list are also unique (i.e., they are not repeated). The words in the two lists are not written with the same (correct) spelling. So, for each word in the shorter list, I want to find the best match in the larger list; besides, while doing this, I want to find matches that minimize the total sum of the square of the distances of each match. I know that the Levenshtein distance is appropriate for measuring the distance between words; however, (as I not from the field) I do not know of  an appropriate algorithm for minimizing the total sum of (squared) distances. **What is the best algorithm for minimizing the total sum of (squared) distances between words in two lists?**

Comment: I believe you could use [word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word2vec) to convert the words and then measure euclidean distance between them or even  [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

Comment: Hi, @SomeDude. Thank you very much for the suggestion, but I was looking specifically for any existing algorithm, rather than a specific function written in some language. I ended up finding about the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) ; it does the job. However, to use this algorithm when the two lists have different sizes, I need to add rows/columns to the distance matrix so as to make it a square matrix. (Btw, I use the Levenshtein distance because it satisfies the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality).)